# Error when installing leidenbase and monocle3 packages in RStudio on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.6 using r4.0.2

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the leidenbase and monocle3 packages in R using the code below:

```
devtools::install_github('cole-trapnell-lab/leidenbase')
devtools::install_github('cole-trapnell-lab/monocle3')
```

Everything I have tried in terms of troubleshooting isn't working. I have been able to install these packages on Windows after a decent amount of troubleshooting previously, but the issue with Mac is unresolved. I have also used the terminal to run the code below, but this resulted in errors as well.

```
% R CMD INSTALL /Users/name/Downloads/leidenbase-0.1.0.tar
```

I am also new to posting on stack overflow, so if there is any additional information that would be helpful, I can share that as well! Thanks in advance!

However, the error messages I receive are:

```
devtools::install_github('cole-trapnell-lab/leidenbase')
```

````
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:63:
In file included from cigraph/src/igraph_blas_internal.h:33:
cigraph/src/config.h:131:9: warning: 'PACKAGE_VERSION' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.1.0"
        ^
<command line>:7:9: note: previous definition is here
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8.2"
        ^
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:80:
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:510:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'dsyrk_' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                BLAS_dsyrk ("L", "N",
                ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:331:2: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_dsyrk'
        BLAS_DSYRK (uplo, trans, &N, &K, alpha, A, &LDA, beta, C, &LDC) ; \
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:132:20: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_DSYRK'
#define BLAS_DSYRK igraphdsyrk_
                   ^
cigraph/src/igraph_lapack_internal.h:86:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdsyrk_'
    #define igraphdsyrk_    dsyrk_
                            ^
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:80:
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:713:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'dpotrf_' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            LAPACK_dpotrf ("L",
            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:365:2: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_dpotrf'
        LAPACK_DPOTRF (uplo, &N, A, &LDA, &INFO) ; \
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:135:23: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_DPOTRF'
#define LAPACK_DPOTRF igraphdpotrf_
                      ^
cigraph/src/igraph_lapack_internal.h:120:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdpotrf_'
    #define igraphdpotrf_   dpotrf_
                            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:713:13: note: did you mean 'zpotrf_'?
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:365:2: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_dpotrf'
        LAPACK_DPOTRF (uplo, &N, A, &LDA, &INFO) ; \
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:135:23: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_DPOTRF'
#define LAPACK_DPOTRF igraphdpotrf_
                      ^
cigraph/src/igraph_lapack_internal.h:120:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdpotrf_'
    #define igraphdpotrf_   dpotrf_
                            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:370:6: note: 'zpotrf_' declared here
void LAPACK_ZPOTRF (char *uplo, BLAS_INT *n, double *A, BLAS_INT *lda,
     ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:144:23: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_ZPOTRF'
#define LAPACK_ZPOTRF zpotrf_
                      ^
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:80:
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:842:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'dtrsm_' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                BLAS_dtrsm ("R", "L", "C", "N",
                ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:257:2: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_dtrsm'
        BLAS_DTRSM (side, uplo, transa, diag, &M, &N, alpha, A, &LDA, B, &LDB);\
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:130:20: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_DTRSM'
#define BLAS_DTRSM igraphdtrsm_
                   ^
cigraph/src/igraph_blas_internal.h:50:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdtrsm_'
    #define igraphdtrsm_    dtrsm_
                            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:842:17: note: did you mean 'ztrsm_'?
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:257:2: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_dtrsm'
        BLAS_DTRSM (side, uplo, transa, diag, &M, &N, alpha, A, &LDA, B, &LDB);\
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:130:20: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_DTRSM'
#define BLAS_DTRSM igraphdtrsm_
                   ^
cigraph/src/igraph_blas_internal.h:50:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdtrsm_'
    #define igraphdtrsm_    dtrsm_
                            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:261:6: note: 'ztrsm_' declared here
void BLAS_ZTRSM (char *side, char *uplo, char *transa, char *diag, BLAS_INT *m,
     ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:139:20: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_ZTRSM'
#define BLAS_ZTRSM ztrsm_
                   ^
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:80:
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:141:40: warning: unused variable 'tstart' [-Wunused-variable]
    double one [2], zero [2], fjk [2], tstart ;
                                       ^

2 warnings and 3 errors generated.
make: *** [cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘leidenbase’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/leidenbase’
Error: Failed to install 'monocle3' from GitHub:
  Failed to install 'leidenbase' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/v3/tdmhdpxd65n0j81wk859jdsw0000gq/T//Rtmph6G87V/file13db735dec4c5/leidenbase_0.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

```
devtools::install_github('cole-trapnell-lab/monocle3')
```
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:63:
In file included from cigraph/src/igraph_blas_internal.h:33:
cigraph/src/config.h:131:9: warning: 'PACKAGE_VERSION' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.1.0"
        ^
<command line>:7:9: note: previous definition is here
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8.2"
        ^
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:80:
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:510:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'dsyrk_' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                BLAS_dsyrk ("L", "N",
                ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:331:2: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_dsyrk'
        BLAS_DSYRK (uplo, trans, &N, &K, alpha, A, &LDA, beta, C, &LDC) ; \
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:132:20: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_DSYRK'
#define BLAS_DSYRK igraphdsyrk_
                   ^
cigraph/src/igraph_lapack_internal.h:86:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdsyrk_'
    #define igraphdsyrk_    dsyrk_
                            ^
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:80:
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:713:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'dpotrf_' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            LAPACK_dpotrf ("L",
            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:365:2: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_dpotrf'
        LAPACK_DPOTRF (uplo, &N, A, &LDA, &INFO) ; \
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:135:23: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_DPOTRF'
#define LAPACK_DPOTRF igraphdpotrf_
                      ^
cigraph/src/igraph_lapack_internal.h:120:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdpotrf_'
    #define igraphdpotrf_   dpotrf_
                            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:713:13: note: did you mean 'zpotrf_'?
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:365:2: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_dpotrf'
        LAPACK_DPOTRF (uplo, &N, A, &LDA, &INFO) ; \
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:135:23: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_DPOTRF'
#define LAPACK_DPOTRF igraphdpotrf_
                      ^
cigraph/src/igraph_lapack_internal.h:120:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdpotrf_'
    #define igraphdpotrf_   dpotrf_
                            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:370:6: note: 'zpotrf_' declared here
void LAPACK_ZPOTRF (char *uplo, BLAS_INT *n, double *A, BLAS_INT *lda,
     ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:144:23: note: expanded from macro 'LAPACK_ZPOTRF'
#define LAPACK_ZPOTRF zpotrf_
                      ^
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:80:
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:842:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'dtrsm_' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                BLAS_dtrsm ("R", "L", "C", "N",
                ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:257:2: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_dtrsm'
        BLAS_DTRSM (side, uplo, transa, diag, &M, &N, alpha, A, &LDA, B, &LDB);\
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:130:20: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_DTRSM'
#define BLAS_DTRSM igraphdtrsm_
                   ^
cigraph/src/igraph_blas_internal.h:50:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdtrsm_'
    #define igraphdtrsm_    dtrsm_
                            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:842:17: note: did you mean 'ztrsm_'?
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:257:2: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_dtrsm'
        BLAS_DTRSM (side, uplo, transa, diag, &M, &N, alpha, A, &LDA, B, &LDB);\
        ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:130:20: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_DTRSM'
#define BLAS_DTRSM igraphdtrsm_
                   ^
cigraph/src/igraph_blas_internal.h:50:29: note: expanded from macro 'igraphdtrsm_'
    #define igraphdtrsm_    dtrsm_
                            ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:261:6: note: 'ztrsm_' declared here
void BLAS_ZTRSM (char *side, char *uplo, char *transa, char *diag, BLAS_INT *m,
     ^
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Include/cholmod_blas.h:139:20: note: expanded from macro 'BLAS_ZTRSM'
#define BLAS_ZTRSM ztrsm_
                   ^
In file included from cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.c:80:
cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/t_cholmod_super_numeric.c:141:40: warning: unused variable 'tstart' [-Wunused-variable]
    double one [2], zero [2], fjk [2], tstart ;
                                       ^

2 warnings and 3 errors generated.
make: *** [cigraph/src/CHOLMOD/Supernodal/cholmod_super_numeric.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘leidenbase’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/leidenbase’
Error: Failed to install 'monocle3' from GitHub:
  Failed to install 'leidenbase' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/v3/tdmhdpxd65n0j81wk859jdsw0000gq/T//Rtmph6G87V/file13db735dec4c5/leidenbase_0.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
````

Comment: I was able to install it. What OS do you have? Also, what version of R and Rtools do you have installed?

Comment: @Phil My iOS version is 10.15.6, and I have R 4.0.2 installed. I can't find how to tell if Rtools is installed on a Mac.

Comment: Actually you wouldn't use Rtools on a Mac. I'm not familiar with Mac OS to help unfortunately.

Comment: @Val  Have you sovled your this problem?

I used MacOs big sur M1 version 11.1 and I also met some problems since installing "leidenbase"  package.

Comment: @Phil Sir, if you installed monocle3 package in Mac successfully  ?

Comment: I don't have a Mac computer.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to download different compilers, this is from the leidenbase docs (https://github.com/cole-trapnell-lab/leidenbase)

```
MacOS Monterey on Apple ARM CPU
R distribution: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/base/R-4.1.2-arm64.pkg C/C++ compilers: Xcode 13.2.1 FORTRAN compiler: gfortran 11.0 https://mac.r-project.org/libs-arm64/gfortran-f51f1da0-darwin20.0-arm64.tar.gz Note: after downloading gfortran, use the command sudo tar fxz gfortran-f51f1da0-darwin20.0-arm64.tar.gz -C / to install it to /opt. For more information, see https://mac.r-project.org/tools/

MacOS Monterey on Intel CPU
R distribution: CRAN package from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-4.0.2.pkg
C/C++ compilers: Apple Xcode 13.2.1 FORTRAN compiler: gfortran 8.2 from https://mac.r-project.org/tools/gfortran-8.2-Mojave.dmg
```

I had a different error than you but ended in a compilation failure for both leidenbase and monocle3. Downloading the above fixed the problem for me